# Error loading operating system with dvd drive connected

Tags: windows-xp

When I connect the external CD drive to computer, I get this error message:

> error loading operating system

When the CD drive is not connected, the computer runs without any problem.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: The boot device order is often set so that the CD drive is checked before the hard disk.  This is a convenience so that you can easily boot up from the CD if there is a problem with the hard disk or you want to boot from the CD for another reason.  If you have a non-bootable CD in the tray when the computer starts up, you get that message.  Remove any CD from the tray when you shut down and it will avoid the problem when you start up.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is what fixer1234 said: your computer is checking the external optical disc drive before the hard drive as it starts up. The error message you're getting is most likely being generated by the BIOS rather than Windows, however. There are two possible solutions to this problem aside from simply disconnecting the drive before starting your computer:

1) Check your system's BIOS to see if the optical drive does indeed have boot priority. Consult your system guide to see what key is used to enter the BIOS and how you can reset the boot order once you're there. You'll most likely want the hard drive to be set as the first boot device.

2) Check if you have a CD in the optical drive as you start your computer. If you do, removing it should make the BIOS skip over the drive when it realizes there's no media to boot from in it.